# How to activate revision info in line number view

Tags: eclipse, svn, revision, line-numbers

I know of an Eclipse feature to show revision information (gradual coloring, more info like revisionnumber, date and author on mouseover) for the last changes in a line in the linenumbers-view.

Does anyone know how to activate this feature for a file, or even better, by default? I accidently hit some shortcut lately which made it show in one file, it does not show up in the others, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called "Show Annotation" and you can find it in the "Team" menu. Since this is a pretty expensive operation, you can't make it the default.

Comment: Correct, thanks :)
Sadly the defined shortcut (ctrl-alt-A) doesn't seem to work, but I can live with that.

Comment: Is that on Windows? The Desktop swallows Ctrl-Alt. Remap the key using the "Keys" preferences.

Comment: Works for me in Windows 7 and Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2

Comment: Yes, pretty expensive at the time. Now it's almost 2020 and some of us _do_ use Linux so this should now be a user's choice, not a developers imposal.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the shortcut: You have to enable the command group `SVN`.

`Window -> Customize Perspective... -> Command Groups Availability -> check "SVN"`.

If you do this, some SVN actions show up in the toolbar which you can remove again (if you want) using the same `Customize Perspective` dialog (tab `Tool Bar Visibility`).

Remapping the shortcut did not work for me but enabling the command group did (with the default key mapping `Ctrl+Alt+A`).

(did not find a way to reply to Aaron's answer so I had to create a new one)

Answer (score 1):

I found my way here while trying to find a way to get the option to show up with code from my git repository.

A lot of the logic in the other answers applies to git too, and I followed the equivalent steps for git but it didn't help me.
It turned out that my projects, although imported from a git repository, hadn't been connected to (or had become disconnected from) the eclipse git integration. I think this happened because I imported the projects before I installed the elcipse git plugin.

I needed to connect them thus:

- Right-click your project (or multiple selected projects) in the Project Explorer
- Select 'Team' > 'Share Project...'
- The default settings were fine for me, but change them if needed
- Click 'Finish'

I found this solution [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1084899/).