# SVN/Eclipse "Show Annotations" -- how to set this to default

Tags: eclipse, svn

SVN has the feature to show on its LHS bar the past revisions on the file open.

I'm currently doing this by `Team > Show Annotation` or by using the short-cut: ^ALT-A.

How can i set this as default on Eclipse-SVN-- so that these annotations will show automatically when i open a file and i won't have to do it from scratch for each and every file i open.

TIA.

Note: i saw [Show annotations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726389/show-annotations-not-working) and [Eclipse: Show Annotation from Previous Revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790689/eclipse-show-annotation-from-previous-revision) among some other useful discussions.

Answer (score 3):

Amazingly, this *still* isn't possible. I'm using Eclipse 4.4.2 and tried the latest Subclipse and Subversive plug-ins - whereas I'm not sure if that choice really matters. I've searched around for hours now, but have to come to the conclusion that it just isn't possible.

Comment: This is very, very annoying.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Yes, indeed. By the way, [10 years ago, the rationale was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1860484/1529709) that "Since this is a pretty expensive operation, you can't make it the default". I wonder if this still holds.